# question about sequences convergent to $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_n)$ be an increasing divergent sequence of positive reals. Then $(1+\frac{1}{x_n})^{x_n}\to e$, it is a standard theory, it is proven by comparing $x_n$ with $[x_n]$ and $[x_n]+1$ and we use a known fact that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is increasing and $e$ is its limit.

Is it true that $(1+\frac{1}{x_n})^{x_n}<e$ for all $n$?

Is $(1+\frac{1}{x_n})^{x_n}$ increasing?

As mentioned, I know this for natural numbers, but couldn't find a more general result for positive reals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also need your sequence to diverge to infinity. The sequence $x_n = 2 - \frac1{n}$ satisfies your hypothesis and obviously the associated quantity does not converge towards $e$.

Comment: missed the word "divergent", sorry, edited

Comment: If you do a Taylor expansion, you get
$\exp(x_n \ln(1+\frac1{x_n})) = \exp(1 - \frac{1}{x_n} + o(\frac{1}{x_n})$, so it is very unlikely that you can get a non-increasing sequence, at least for large values of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be given by $f(t) = (1 + \frac{1}{t})^t = \exp(t \ln(1+\frac{1}{t}))$

To show it is increasing function of $t$, it is equivalent to showing that function $g: (0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ given by $g(t) = t\ln(1+\frac{1}{t})$ is increasing.

We have $g'(t) = \ln(1+\frac{1}{t}) + t\cdot\frac{-1}{t^2}\frac{t}{t+1} = \ln(1+\frac{1}{t}) - \frac{1}{t+1}$

So that

$g''(t) = \frac{-1}{(t+1)t} + \frac{1}{(t+1)(t+1)} = \frac{1}{t+1}(\frac{1}{t+1} - \frac{1}{t})$

We immediatelly see that $g''$ is negative on the whole $(0,\infty)$, which means that $g'$ is decreasing on the whole $(0,\infty)$. But $\lim_{t \to 0^+} g'(t) = + \infty$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} g'(t) = 0$, so that by continuity, $g'$ is positive on the whole $(0,\infty)$, which means $g$ is increasing on the whole $(0,\infty)$. So as long as your sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is increasing, then $(1+\frac{1}{x_n})^{x_n}$ is increasing, too. The bound $(1+\frac{1}{x_n})^{x_n} < e$ is then clear.

Answer (score 1):

$(1+\frac1{x})^x < e$
is equivalent to
$x\ln(1+\frac1{x}) < 1$.

For $z > 0$,
$\ln(1+z)
=\int_1^{1+z} \dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int_0^{z} \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\lt\int_0^{z} dt
=z$
so,
for $x > 0$,
$x\ln(1+\frac1{x})
< x\frac1{x}
=1$.